# In Ark, Center, Island, or Scorched Earth?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

With which one should a new player start? And is it possible to move character between this by using the obelisk as long all are public servers?

Comment: You may want to remove the first part, as it is opinion-based and would be a valid reason for this question to be closed. The second part is okay though.

Comment: @Vemonus Earth, my bad

Comment: @Angzuril that's what I thought but I didn't want to assume and wasn't in a place where I could check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a new player, you really should start on either [The Island](http://ark.gamepedia.com/The_Island) or [The Center](http://ark.gamepedia.com/The_Center). Both of these maps have a variety of regions, many of which are not immediately hostile. The [Scorched Earth desert](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Scorched_Earth) is much more challenging due to the lack of water, and generally hostile environment.

You can use an [Obelisk](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Obelisk) to transfer your character to another server, which may have a different map (So you can switch to the Scorched Earth desert at a later time). There are several restrictions however.

You cannot transfer from a PvE server to PvP server or vice versa. You cannot transfer from an unofficial server to an official server, and this includes transferring from your own server (even single player). Additionally, a server could have [configuration](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Server_Configuration) to completely ban uploads and/or downloads to the server (preventUploadSurvivors, preventDownloadSurvivors).